# Creating subselect string with ActiveRecord (Rails Tutorial 2nd edition, Listing 11.45)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, railstutorial.org, subquery

In [listing 11.45](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#code%3afrom_users_followed_by_final) of Chapter 11 of The Rails Tutorial 2nd edition, the `from_users_followed_by` class method of the `Micropost` class is defined as follows:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                         WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", 
          user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

In [footnote 13](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#fn:11.13) of the chapter, there is a link to [this blog post](http://pivotallabs.com/users/jsusser/blog/articles/567-hacking-a-subselect-in-activerecord) which says you can use the ActiveRecord internal method `construct_finder_sql` with the `send` method if you want to create a subselect string.  So, I attempted to replace the `followed_user_ids` string with:

```
followed_user_ids = Relationship.send(:construct_finder_sql,
                                      select: "followed_id",
                                      conditions: { follower_id: :user_id })
```

Only problem is that `construct_finder_sql` was [depreciated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/construct_finder_sql/class) in Rails 3, so as well as not knowing if what I wrote was at all correct, I can't use it anyway.  So, is there a Rails 3 way of creating a subselect string using ActiveRecord (that could preferably still use the `:user_id` parameter) that would work in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your seb-select as a separate query and then use `to_sql` to get the SQL:

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
  followed = Relationship.select(:followed_id)
                         .where(:follower_id => user.id)
                         .to_sql
  where("user_id in (#{followed}) or user_id = :user_id", :user_id => user.id)
end
```

Things like `M.select(...).where(...)` just build `ActiveRecord::Relation` instances and those  build the query piece by piece, nothing is sent to the database until you ask for some results (in way or another). So, you can use the AREL stuff to build a query and then `to_sql` it to get the SQL version.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer; it got me to the code I wanted.  Within my code, I decided I wanted to use the `:user_id` parameter in both statements, so I've taken your answer but just substituted your `where` clause for `.where("follower_id = :user_id")`.  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to drag this back up, but after upgrading the [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org/) gem on my app to version `1.7.0`, this answer (including my slightly altered answer) now triggers a high confidence SQL injection warning on the `where` clause.  The original code in the question does not trigger this warning.  I can't see the difference between them and am wondering if it's a false positive, but nevertheless, is there a more "secure" to rewrite the code in the answer?

Comment: @Paul: Brakeman is only noticing that you're using string interpolation inside SQL without understanding the context. The code is safe. You could de-AR it and write it out as one big SQL string I suppose.

Comment: Thanks so much for the follow-up and confirming the code is safe.  I guess that de-ARing it would just consist of reverting the code to how it is in the question(?)  Do you know if there's any way to interpolate inside SQL using these AREL methods while "understanding the context" of the interpolation?  If you want I can ask this as a separate SO question.

Comment: @Paul: yes but inline the subquery to avoid interpolation to avoid the warning. I've never been able to get AR to do any non-trivial SQL (subqueries, derived tables, ...) in a workable fashion; on the upside, I'm pretty comfortable with SQL so I don't mind. Asking a separate question would be good, you might get someone else's point of view and that might suit you more than mine does.